# How do I transfer my iOS developer profile to another computer?

Tags: xcode, data-transfer, certificate

I got a new MBP and would like to transfer my certificates and profiles from my old computer.  According to [TN 2250, under "Transferring Your Identities,"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG24) I need to transfer three sets of items:

- all iPhone Developer certificates in your keychain
- all iPhone Distribution certificates in your keychain
- all Provisioning Profiles in the Xcode Organizer > Devices tab > Provisioning Profiles section under "Library"

TN 2250 suggests I click a link entitled "Transfer Your Developer Profile to Another Computer" to find out how to do said transfer, but that link effectively gives a 404 and refreshes to a page called "About Xcode"

How do I transfer my developer profile to another computer?

My old machine is running OS X 10.6.8 and Xcode 4.2 (4C199).
The new machine is running OS X 10.7.4 and Xcode 4.3.3 (4E3002).

Comment: And in the "About XCode" user guide you'll find this page (last section): http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/080-Manage_Your_Devices/manage_devices.html

Comment: thank you for pointing that out; I hadn't seen it (obviously).  :-)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Import/Export works differently in Xcode 5+. [This Apple Developer guide](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev8a2822e0b) shows you how to do it.

Your account is shown under **Xcode** → **Preferences** → **Accounts**, and can be exported by clicking the gear icon ([image]) in the lower-left.

[image: Import/Export Apple ID and Code Signing Assets]

Comment: Will this work If both computers are logged in with the [same] developer account?

Comment: Somebody any idea? I want to work on my iOS project from my mac-mini AND macbook with the same account. does this work?

Comment: I log in with the same account on an iMac and a MacBook Pro with no trouble. Take the account on the first device, export it, and then on the second device do an import.

Comment: This exports all accounts listed.  How can one account be exported?

Comment: Importing profile from Xcode 13 to Xcode 14 on a newer mac caused crash.

Answer (score 15):

You can do this from within Xcode.

From the Organiser, on the devices tab, you can export your developer profile to a file which you can then import into Xcode on another computer.

The step by step process is explained in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/080-Manage_Your_Devices/manage_devices.html near the bottom in the section entitled **Transfer Your Developer Profile to Another Computer**

Note that if you don't have a Teams section in your Organizer - Devices, you can just drag and drop the password-protected Developer profiles export-file, onto the Xcode icon in the toolbar.
[image]

Comment: ah wait; I don't have a "Teams" section in Organizer -> Devices.

Comment: Do you have a profiles section? with Import Export buttons along the bottom.

Comment: Ah! "Developer profile" under library!  thanks!

Comment: I'm one step closer, but now getting a different error; thanks for your help!

Comment: The **step by step** link no longer exists now.

Answer (score 3):

You need to export your private key from Key Chain access of Mac OSX in which certificates are running successfully or from which developer certificate made and download certificates from [Apple Developer Portal](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action), it will work as it works for me.

Comment: Xcode 4 makes the process a lot easier, allowing you to wrap up your dev profile along with your public and private keys and import them into Xcode on another machine without having to go to the KeyChain and pull them out one by one.

Comment: Ah, this is traditional method which I am doing since I started development. You may right Xcode 4 providing those process which I learned today.